# Probability of men winning both tickets

Tags: probability

At a gathering consisting of $3$ men and $11$ women, two door prizes are awarded. Find the probability that both prizes are won by men. The winning ticket is not replaced.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  When you pose a question here, you should provide some context for the problem.   For a computational problem such as this one, you should indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck.  Also, indicating where you encountered the problem is a good idea so that you receive responses tailored to your level of mathematical experience.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each person has one ticket and each is equally likely to be chosen, the probability a man will hold the first ticket drawn is 3/14.  After that, there are 2 men and 11 women.  Each ticket, again, being equally likely to be chosen, the probability a ticket held by a man will be chosen is 2/13.

The probability the first two chosen are both men is (3/14)(2/13).

Answer (score 3):

We can choose 2 men out of 3 without replacements in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways. Similarly we can choose any 2 people without replacement in $\binom{14}{2}$ ways . Therefore the required answer is $$\frac{favourable \space outcomes }{total \space outcomes} = \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{14}{2}}=\frac{3}{91}$$

Answer (score 1):

3/14 * 2/13 is it. 3/91 is how it simplifies.

Answer (score 0):

Using permutations. 
For 3 men = 3P2 (since there are 2 awards and 3 men). 
For 11 women = 11P(since there are 2 awards and11 women). 
For all = (11+3)P2 (For men + For women).

Since we want to know for men. 
Probability = permutations for men / permutation for all.

Permutations for men=3P2 = 3!/(3-2)! = (3*2*1)/1.       {! denotes factorial, for ex 5! = 5*4*3*2*1} = 6.

Permutations for all = 14P2 =14!/(14-2)! = 14!/12!
=(14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1).  (12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1). 
=14*13. 
=182.

Probability of men getting two tickets = 6/182 = 3/91.

Comment: Please consider [formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) your post in order to make it more readable.

Comment: Surely I will edit it